# Display word/pdf file on web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have few files in doc/docx/pdf format stored on server's folder and their path are saved in database. I wish to fetch the path of these files from database and then display it on my website.

In the database the files are stored in this format

```
id    path
1    abc/request/file1.docx
2    abc/request/file2.pdf
3    abc/request/file3.docx
```

To display the file i used the following method

```
$a = $data->path;
$b = 'http://example.com/';
$r = $b.$a;  

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=<?php echo $r; ?>&embedded=true" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Issue

> Earlier the file was getting displayed but all of a sudden it is not getting displayed now

I did the following checks to see the validity of file

> 1) File is in proper format and is not corrupted and does exist on server folder
>   2) The console is not giving any errors
>   3) Tried to run http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/abc/request/file1.docx on browser, there also the file is not getting displayed, however the other example url given on net are working

Can anyone please tell how to correct the error. And I would also appreciate if anyone could tell any other way(using jquery, javascript or any but reliable way) to display the files on website without disturbing the formatting of the original file

Comment: `Earlier the file was getting displayed but all of a sudden it is not getting displayed now` - what did you change between "earlier" and "now"

Comment: @Jaromanda X didn't changed anything, infact havn't worked on that entire webpage

Comment: Google may have stopped allowing embedding of doc viewing in iframes since it last worked.

Comment: @flauntster if thats the case, can you please suggest some alternate way to fulfill the objective

Comment: pdf files are easy ... .docx not so easy

Comment: note, the `docs.google.com/gview` works for me - maybe there's some quota thing happening - check the developer tools network tab to see what's happening for you

Comment: @Jaromanda X I was just checking the tab and it started to work, it looks kind of unreliable as it may stop and start working any time, is there any other way which i can use to display the files... u said pdf is easy.. can you please tell how i can do so

Comment: all decent browsers handle pdf natively ... IE needs mozilla's pdf.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PDF, you can use [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org) to render.

For doc/docx, consider using Microsoft Office Viewer as a walkaround if Google Docs Viewer is not stable enough to you

```html
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http%3A%2F%2Fieee802%2Eorg%3A80%2Fsecmail%2FdocIZSEwEqHFr%2Edoc' width='100%' height='900px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
```

P/S: Don't know why the code snippet is not working, but you can take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/gcuzq343/

Answer (score 1):

you can use 
**1. google docs viewer**

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/my-document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

**2. Microsoft viewer**

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://example.com/my-document.doc.doc' width='800px' height='600px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
```

Comment: sad.  only works if the document is not behind a password.  be cool if you can send the bytes somehow