# laravel 5.4,phpword: how to display a word doc with read only permission without forcing download?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laravel and I use **phpword** to edit a word doc file.

I want once I save it I can display it in **read only permission**.

I want to display it directly **without forcing download**.

I tried this code but it forces the download.

Here is my code :

```
  public function create()
  {
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();
    //Ajouter l'image
    $section->addImage(
      'C:\wamp\www\Stage_2\public\images\mobilis256.png',
      array(
        'width'         => 100,
        'height'        => 100,
        'marginTop'     => -1,
        'marginLeft'    => -1,
        'wrappingStyle' => 'behind'
        ));
    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    try {
      $objWriter->save(storage_path('helloWorld.docx'));
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {}
    $filename = 'helloWorld.docx';
    $path = storage_path($filename);
    return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/docx',
      'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
      ]);
  }
```

i tried also

```
return response()->file(storage_path('helloWorld.docx'));
```

but always the same result.

what should I do, and **how can i disply it in read only permission?**

Comment: You can't display a doc in the browser unless they have some kind of plugin to handle that.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Do it another way. PDF or something.

Comment: so you mean I should convert a word doc to pdf, i will search how can i do it but what about permission i want to display it in read only?do you know any doc that wan help me, thanks.

Comment: You could use the microsoft viewer in an iframe like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41114601/1858357

Comment: PHPWord has Writers to convert generate the document to HTML or as PDF, why not use one of those?

Comment: have you read that :The PHPWord converter is not working ( https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/472 ) so I cannot use that. Can anyone recommend something to achieve this?

Comment: and also : Unfortunatelly PHPWord is abandoned. No more commits, no more merged pull requests, last version was at Agoust with slight differences.

I use it, but it's terrible buggy. Some bugs, you will need to fix yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution finally so what I did was:

I saved the document as **html file** like this :

```
 $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
    try {
      $objWriter->save(storage_path('helloWorld.html'));
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {}
```

Then using **dompdf** :
   https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf I **convert the html file
   to pdf** :

```
 return PDF::loadFile(storage_path('helloWorld.html'))->save(storage_path('helloWorldPdf.html'))->stream('download.pdf');
```

So like this I can preview the file **without forcing** the downloading and to not redo the work.

The final code look like this:

```
  use PDF;
  public function create()
  {
  $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
  $section = $phpWord->addSection();
  //Ajouter l'image
  $section->addImage(
  'C:\wamp\www\Stage_2\public\images\mobilis256.png',
  array(
  'width'         => 100,
  'height'        => 100,
  'marginTop'     => -1,
  'marginLeft'    => -1,
  'wrappingStyle' => 'behind'
  ));
  // Saving the document as HTML file...
  $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
  try {
  $objWriter->save(storage_path('helloWorld.html'));
  }catch(Exception $e)
  {}
  return PDF::loadFile(storage_path('helloWorld.html'))->save(storage_path('helloWorldPdf.html'))->stream('download.pdf');
  }
```

> Just if you want to use **domppdf** to do this conversion do not do that :
>
> After updating composer add the following lines to register provider in >bootstrap/app.php
>
> `$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);`
>
> To change the configuration, copy the config file to your config folder and >enable it in bootstrap/app.php:
>
> `$app->configure('dompdf');`
>   Here the explication of the kind of error you will get .
>   https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/192